# Trying to figure out pow source code in python | My function gone wrong

Tags: python, function, pow

I am doing an exercise of my school book which says : 
"Write a code in python which calculates the power of a number without using the function pow()." 
The first parts of my function are working fine. But when it comes to # elif b > 1 
 
It just returns the number of a * b, not the a ** b ... 
I would be really happy if you could help me with that. I have spent at least 1 hour trying to fix it.

```
def mypow(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    if b == 1:
        return a
    elif b > 1:
        x = 0 
        for i in range(b):
            x += 1 * a
        return x 
    # I know I got to add what happens if the b is negative, but I will do this after fixing the bug.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be adding instead of multiplying.

```
for i in range(b):
    x *= a
```

You don't need special cases for 0 and 1; `b == 0` is sufficient.

```
def mypow(a, b):
    answer = 1  # a ** 0 == 1
    # The loop is only entered if b > 0
    for _ in range(b):
        answer *= a
    return answer
```

Comment: Thank you sir you helped a lot ! I got you, I will accept your answer in a while ! I think it was foolish of me ..

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because you're adding `a` to `x` `b` times. You should multiply, not add.

Comment: You got a point on that. I fixed that but now it returns zero when a == 2 and b == 3. I mean now it is like : x *= 1 * a